# uninstall libfreenect which installed with cmake

Tags: macos, cmake, kinect

I installed OpenKinect/libfreenect with cmake in OSX.

I wanna uninstall it.But, I dont know how to do it.

Please teach me.

Answer (score 0):

If your build directory contains cmake_uninstall.cmake file, you can run

```
cmake -P cmake_uninstall.cmake
```

If not, you can only use install_manifest.txt file to manually delete all files.
Also check available make targets, maybe there is "uninstall" or "deinstall" target.